# Cannot set property closed of #<Readable> which has only a getter

Tags: reactjs

i'm using npm start in react project to serve on localhost, everything was fine, but yesterday i got this problem :

````
TypeError: Cannot set property closed of #<Readable> which has only a getter
    at FsReadStream.close (D:\Nageeb\Me\مشاريعي\BravoB2C(5)\Front-end\front-end\node_modules\memfs\lib\volume.js:2047:17)
    at FsReadStream._destroy (D:\Nageeb\Me\مشاريعي\BravoB2C(5)\Front-end\front-end\node_modules\memfs\lib\volume.js:2032:10)      
    at _destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:109:10)
    at class_1.destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:71:5)
    at class_1.<anonymous> (D:\Nageeb\Me\مشاريعي\BravoB2C(5)\Front-end\front-end\node_modules\memfs\lib\volume.js:1962:22)        
    at class_1.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on class_1 instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Node.js v18.12.0
```
`
i made a new project but also the same problem
````

Comment: Having the same issue with node 19.5.0

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue with vueJs, npm upgrade was able to fix it

Comment: FYI, I had this problem using the ssh2 module v1.5.0 within node v18.13.0.  `Connection :: error :: TypeError: Cannot set property closed of #<Writable> which has only a getter`   Upgrading to ssh2 v1.11.0 avoided the error.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue. Installing `[memfs][1]` solved the problem for me. 
Try: `npm install memfs`

Answer (score 2):

I was faced also this issue. I just tried npm install memfs and problem was solved.

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as below. I recommend deletion.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the problem, as stated in the error message, is with the package `memfs` and as presented by @Sachin and @Suvin, installing a more recent version of it will solve the problem:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property closed of #<Readable> which has only a getter
    at FsReadStream.close (...\node_modules\memfs\...)
```

I had a similar issue and in my case, it was with another package named `restify`, nevertheless, the solution was the same: *update the package*.

[Mozila: TypeError: setting getter-only property "x"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Getter_only)

[Restify Issue Ticket (solved)](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/1925)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good thing to do, but you can manually upgrade the memfs package in your package.json as a last solution

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing "TypeError: Cannot set property closed of # which has only a getter"

After that I have installed memfs and the problem is solved.

Try : `npm install memfs`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Installing memfs solved the problem.
Try: npm install memfs